# I have many drivers (USB audio card, bluetooth) that have been specially configured and hacked

Tags: windows-7, drivers

If I upgrade to Windows 7, will these drivers be "over-written"?

**Can I use Windows 7 while keeping all my current settings for everything?**

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain :

> that have been specially configured and hacked.

It's unlikely that your previous Windows XP drivers will work (assuming your current OS is WIndows XP from the tags). Windows 7 will update the drivers. Perhaps after installing you can you the "have disk" method and point to your specially configured drivers, but bad drivers can result in recurring BSOD's.